# How to style the Action Bar Overflow on devices with a hardware menu button?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles, android-optionsmenu

this is how I style the Action Bar Overflow on stock android:

```
<style name="DropDownNav.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background</item>
</style>
```

But the specified custom selector is not applied to the popup options menu on Samsung devices with a hardware button, instead it is default blue.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192761/how-to-style-text-in-action-overflow-menu-on-device-with-android4-0-and-hardwar) and tried to apply

```
<style name="ListPopupWindow.IvuTheme" parent="android:Widget.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

but to no effect.

What style do I need to inherit (and what is the corresponding attribute in my theme) in order to change the selector in the latter hardware button options menu?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score -1):

1) Extend your Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }
}
```

2) add to Manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:name=".MyApplication">
```

Comment: It is working. I use it in a real app. And minus is inappropriate.