# My overflow menu doesn't seen in xml layout

Tags: android, xml

When i run the app overflow menu seen in emulator(i mean that three dots or lines on right top) , but while i was working, it doesn't seen on xml layout why ?? These are codes ;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class OverflowApp extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bambam){
        super.onCreate(bambam);
        setContentView(R.layout.overflow_xml);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main , menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and xml codes ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no such thing as a layout for action overflow menu. The content that is to be displayed is stored in the following form.

`<menu ...>
    <item android:id="..." android:title="..."/>
    <item android:id="..." android:title="..."/>
    <item android:id="..." android:title="..."/>
    ...
</menu>`

This file can be accessed from the menu directory in the res folder.
You can add, delete or change the menu items but not how they look from here.

As far as the appearance is concerned, you can change the appearance only in terms of the colors using styles. You can start with the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192761/how-to-style-text-in-action-overflow-menu-on-device-with-android4-0-and-hardwar).

Comment: Can't i tell my problem ? Three dots or line in right top doesn't appear on xml layout editor. I didn't mention such a layout for action overflow menu.

Comment: It is not meant to appear in the XML file. The action bar appears automatically for every activity unless you change the theme to NoActionBar. So from your comment all I understand is that you do not want the overflow button on the action bar is it?

Comment: Firstly thanks for your interest . I use DarkActionBar , i see ActionBar in xml layout design but i can't see three dots or line which located right of this action bar. (In emulator it is seen and there is no problem about program running , but in my xml layout design it cannot seen.)